# Global Application Settings in ASP MVC + nInject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I've trawled the globe for an answer to this, but cannot find anything.

I am in the process of rewriting an ASP WebForms application to ASP MVC. I've been using nInject and for most of the objects this is fine. What I'm struggling with is how to surface global application settings for use in every view.

The WebForms app uses a static class with a static constructor that, using an EF context converts the settings table (name, value) to a dictionary, that the properties then read from.

What is the best way to do this in MVC? Clearly I could still use the static class, but how would I inject the ISettingRepository, as a static constructor has to be parameterless?

Sorry if this isn't very clear, it's kind of difficult to explain =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason to stay with the `static` class, especially when you're using `Ninject`.

Change your static class to a normal class that accepts `ISettingsRepository` in it's constructor, and have `Ninject` instantiate it for you in a `Singleton` scope.

Alternatively, you can stay with the `static` class and use `Ninject` to resolve your `ISettingsRepository` in `Service Locator` mode, something like:

```
public static class MyAppSettings
{
      private static ISettingsRepository _rep;

      MyAppSettings()
      {
      }

      public static string Get(string key)
      {
            // instantiate if null
            if (_rep == null)
                _rep = kernel.Get<ISettingsRepository>();

            // ...
      }

      // ...
}
```